# Language code and i18n in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization

I have created a `.po` file to translate the custom template text. But this isn't what I want to achieve. I only want Wordpress to translate the texts when it's on the matching language code `.com/en/..`. Now it translates everything on the same URL which means I can only see one language and for example not visit the Dutch version by going to `.com/nl/..`

Is it possible to add language code in the URL which translates to matching language?

Hopefully this makes sense, if not I'll explain better.

Answer (score 2):

To translate a Wordpress Website, you may need a plugin that make this. As much as you add a "/ nl", if you do not have a plugin that translates the whole web and you modify the language of wordpress, the wordpress itself will not know that you have changed the language and will always show the same ".po".